# Set active class on one element at the time

Tags: jquery, html, css, onclick

What I have is a table  representation of available times/date. The user is able to choose a time by clicking on the link "Choose". When clicking on this link the class "active" is set, but what I want is when the user chooses a other time the previous class is removed and set on the new element **only**.

What I have so far:

```
<div class="wrapper-div">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="date">monday, 2015 09 02 </div>
        <div class="time">12:10</div>
        <div class="select"><a href="#">Choose <span class="select-arrow"></span></a>            
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="date">thuesday, 2015 06 22</div>
        <div class="time">12:30</div>
        <div class="select"><a href="#">Choose <span class="select-arrow"></span></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="date">wensday, 2015 02 9</div>
        <div class="time">09:15</div>
        <div class="select"><a href="#">Choose <span class="select-arrow"></span></a></div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$('.select a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents().eq(1).addClass('active');
    $('.wrapper-div div').each(function(){
        removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

And my working fiddle: http://goo.gl/E5hhyn

What is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `each` syntax is incorrect as you don't call `removeClass` on any jQuery object. The need for `each` itself is redundant anyway. Try this:

```
$('.select a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.wrapper-div div').removeClass('active'); // remove first
    $(this).parents().eq(1).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gtog33qk/1/

```
$('.select a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.wrapper-div div').each(function(i,e){
        $(e).removeClass('active');
    });
    $(this).closest('.row').addClass('active');

});
```

Just changed a little code, used closest to find the complete active row, and you need to use removeClass on an element, as explained by Rory

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery's .find() method to find the class you want to remove, then use jQuery's .remove() method to remove the class. With the class now gone, just add your new .active class.

Answer (score 0):

you first add the Class and than you remove all of the "active" classes, if you first remove all the classes "active" and then add it to the clicked one it should work.

```
$('.wrapper-div .row').each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
$(this).parents().find(".row:first").addClass('active');
```